# Unknown reason for error with Play! Framework project & use only java in project

Tags: java, eclipse, playframework

I'm getting an error on a recently created Play! Project and I don't know why. Can any one help me? The error I'm getting is the following: "index cannot be resolved"
[image: The error I'm getting is the following: "index cannot be resolved"]

I have another question also, in the play! framework web, it says the following and I have no idea how to do it, can someone explain to me a little what that is and how to do it?:

> If you do not want to install Scala IDE and have only Java sources in your > project, then you can set the following:

```
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java           // Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)  // Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes 
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)                  // Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that .class files for views and routes are present
```

Comment: i always ignore this!

Comment: @Smiley Those are two different questions. You should write two different questions in StackOverflow. It makes it easier to answer and to find for others.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**First question)**

Eclipse doesn't know about your views (also called [templates](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/JavaTemplates)) yet. They are Scala classes that will be generated from your actual `my_view_name.scala.html` files during compiling. So after you compiled you just have to run `activator eclipse` (or '
`play eclipse` with older versions of Play) and those errors magically disappear.

**Second question)**

I've never set [those](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/IDE). I guess you have to set in your `project/plugins.sbt`

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbteclipse" % "sbteclipse-plugin" % "4.0.0")
```

and, if you use no Scala (Java-only), in your `build.sbt`

```
EclipseKeys.projectFlavor := EclipseProjectFlavor.Java           // Java project. Don't expect Scala IDE
EclipseKeys.createSrc := EclipseCreateSrc.ValueSet(EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedClasses, EclipseCreateSrc.ManagedResources)  // Use .class files instead of generated .scala files for views and routes 
EclipseKeys.preTasks := Seq(compile in Compile)                  // Compile the project before generating Eclipse files, so that .class files for views and routes are present
```

Comment: Perfect @Kris, Thank you very much. That was pretty much the problem :)

Comment: Also make sure to upgrade `sbteclipse` to version `5.1.0` (which was released on January 12th 2017) - it fixes a bug where the views were not put on the classpath when you had you project not compiled before.